# PHP Conditional with Multiple Parameters

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using in a wordpress theme, the **Redux Framework**, to manage the general options, and the **ACF** for additional options in the posts.

Both in the options panel and in the post fields, you have the option
to disable and enable the name of the **author** of the post.

These are the variables and their values, which I call to show or not the name of the **author**

**On the panel:**
`$opt_panel_author` **values:** true / false

**On custom fields**
`$opt_field_author` **values:** inherit / yes / no

**Calling on the theme like this:**

```
<?php if ($opt_panel_author == true && $opt_field_author) { ?>
    <span class = "post-meta-author"> By: John Doe </ span>
<?php } ?>
```

It works to some extent.

What I need now is:

**1st** - When the option in **Panel** is `true` and that of **Custom Field** is`inherit` **show** the author's name.

**2nd** - When the **panel** option is `false` and the **Custom Field** is`yes` show the author's name.

**3rd** - When the **panel** option is `true` and **Custom Field** is`no` **do not show** the author's name.

**4rd** - When the Options Panel and Custom Fields are disabled. Show the name of the author.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, the `$opt_field_author` is a simple string scalar type? If so, you will need to test like this: `<?php if ($opt_panel_author == true && $opt_field_author == 'yes') { ?>`

Comment: @ShaunBebbers Yeah, like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php if (
           ($opt_panel_author && $opt_field_author == 'inherit') || 
           (!$opt_panel_author && $opt_field_author == 'yes') || 
           (!$opt_panel_author && $opt_field_author == 'no')
         ) { ?>

<span class = "post-meta-author"> By: John Doe </ span>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Not exactly. In `$ opt_panel_author` there are only two values ` true` and `false` in` $ opt_field_author` three values, `yes`, `no`, and `inherit`

Comment: That's whats been tested..  $opt_panel_author it's the same that $opt_panel_author == true and !$opt_panel_author it's the same that $opt_panel_author == false

Comment: you also have to remember that test 3 is basically irrelevant.

Comment: @DioneiMiodutzki Okay, I made a mess here, it works. I would like that when the plugin is disabled. Show the author.